# Deploying multiple apps with CloudDeploy and Skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, google-cloud-deploy, gcloud-deploy

I'm using GCP CloudDeploy and Skaffold to deploy my docker containers to CloudRun (roughly following [this GCP tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/cloud-run-app-deployment-with-cloud-deploy#0)). It works well with only one container but now that I'm trying to add another one, I cannot make it work.

This is my `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3alpha1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myname
profiles:
- name: dev
  manifests:
    rawYaml:
    - service_a.yaml
deploy:
  cloudrun:
    region: myregion
```

I have two services, `a` and `b`. It works with either `service_a.yaml` or `service_b.yaml` (I can deploy each of them if I define its yaml as the only `rawYaml`), but not with both passed as a two-element list to `rawYaml`. If I include two and call `gcloud deploy releases create`, the release fails without any informative logs or error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the [GCP tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/cloud-run-app-deployment-with-cloud-deploy#2) you were following, on the Review configuration files, for them to run multiple applications they were creating another rawYaml.

As an example:

```
- name: dev
  manifests:
    rawYaml:
    - deploy-dev.yaml
- name: qa
  manifests:
    rawYaml:
    - deploy-qa.yaml
```

You can try to deploy your service-a.yaml and service-b.yaml at the same time.

Comment: Hi Dion V, the snippet you suggest seems to create different profiles. I've tried different combinations of profiles but couldn't make it work.